# Simple n-gram algorithm

Tags: algorithm, string-matching, n-gram

I am looking for an algorithm (or C#, Java source) that can find n-grams in sentences. Specifically, I have a vocabulary of 100 words (w1 to w100) and sentences composed of these words (s1, s2, s3 etc).

The sentences are variable length from 1 to 100 words, the words can appear in any order in the sentence (but once placed in a sentence the order counts), the words can repeat any number of times.

I am looking for an algorithm that will take a threshold number and return the n-grams in the sentences that occur above the threshold and the sentences in which the n-grams appear.

I am also interested in a gap tolerant algorithm that finds common words in the same order but with gaps in between.

Thanks in advance. I hope this question is stated clearly and within the scope of StackOverflow.

Comment: Just as a point of clarification, are we using n-grams to refer to groups of `n` letters or are we defining it to be groups of `n` words?